# how to fix "from mediapipe.python._framework_bindings import resource_util ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found."

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, mediapipe

When I try to import the mediapipe module which I successfully installed using "pip install mediapipe" I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user_name\Anaconda3\envs\env_name\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from mediapipe.python import *
  File "C:\Users\user_name\Anaconda3\envs\env_name\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from mediapipe.python._framework_bindings import resource_util
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I am using the anaconda terminal and jupyter notebook to run the codes and my OS is Windows 10. I have tried multiple solutions I found online but none of them worked for me. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There you type in your terminal `pip install msvc-runtime` to avoid the error.

Than it will work fine. If you want to know more about mediapipe visit:

https://google.github.io/mediapipe/

Thanks.